# How to display Activity Indicator instead Gallery Image?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-layout

i want loading images for net. I display data along with Image Gallery... In gallery i am displaying imageView as an gallery Item. I just want to display an activity Indicator in ma gallery until the actual image loaded and then displayed. Functionality is used in iphone. Activity indicator look like this...

[Activity Indicator](http://getsetgames.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/ActivityIndicator.gif)

How i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got it. Use progress-bar in Layout XML inside a FrameLayout. A thread associated with Progress-bar to animate it. After loading the image I get Selected View form gallery(FrameView) and remove all the view form it. Then add my image to and ImageView and then add ImageView to frame layout. I Try post my code but it answer is not submitting.(the Connect me for code...

Answer (score 0):

`Activity.setProgressBarVisibilty`